# django create object from recursive model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have problem with creating object with recursive relation. So the scenario is right after create organization, insert user to just-created organization.

```
# models.py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    photo_path = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'organization'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrganizationLevel(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'organization_level'
        unique_together = ('name', 'organization')


class OrganizationUnit(models.Model):
    organization_level = models.ForeignKey(
        OrganizationLevel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    position = models.PointField(geography=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'organization_unit'
        unique_together = ('name', 'organization_level')

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    tokenexp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    photo_path = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    organization_unit = models.ForeignKey(
        OrganizationUnit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

So from given models, here's the flow:

1. Create organization
2. Create organization level instance from organization instance
3. Create organization unit instance from organization level instance

I already try like this but got error

```
org = Organization.objects.create(
            name=name,
            code=code.upper()
        )
        org.save()

        lvl = OrganizationLevel.objects.create(
            organization=org,
            parent=org.id,
            name="Level1"
        )
        lvl.save()

        unit = OrganizationUnit.objects.create(
            name="Unit Name",
            organization_level=lvl,
            parent=lvl.id
        )
        unit.save()
```

**Cannot assign "6": "OrganizationLevel.parent" must be a "OrganizationLevel" instance.**

And what's the right answer?

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, but what is not clear is what you are trying to do. `org` is an Organization, but `parent` is a recursive relationship so needs to be an instance of OrganizationLevel. So why are you trying to pass `org.id` as the value?

Comment: Note, this doesn't have anything to do with inserting the user.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what I'm trying to do is creating parent, but I don't know how to do it so I passed .id

Comment: But what is the parent in this scenario? Where is it supposed to be coming from?

Comment: This data model doesn't make much sense. What does OrganizationLevel say about Organization? What is their relationship. From what you write, every organization level can only be tied to one organization, which means that for each organization there are custom levels that cannot be reused for other organizations. I think you should look into ManyToMany for that one.

Comment: @Melvyn whether the op's OrganizationLevel should belong to Organization or not depends on the specifications, so you cannot tell whether it makes sense or not without reading the specifications.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You're right. But with the generic name "Level1" I'm betting on design flaw. :)

Comment: @Melvyn having both Unit and Level hierarchies when Unit is also bound to a Level instance seems indeed a bit suprising and this _might_ be a design flaw - or not, no one can say without a decent knowledge of the problem domain. Sometimes business apps have to accomodate very peculiar and arbitrary rules which easily lead to seemingly overcomplificated or just plain wtf-y database schema that nonetheless make perfect sense in the project's context.

Answer (score 2):

For a recursive relationship (ForeignKey to self) the foreign key needs to accept null - else you will never be able to create at least the first instance (else it would need a reference to another pre-existing record, which cannot be created without a reference to yet another pre-existing record etc - chicken & egg problem...), so you want:

```
class OrganizationLevel(models.Model):
    # ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

and

```
class OrganizationUnit(models.Model):
    # ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

And when creating the first Level and Unit, leave those blanks:

```
    lvl = OrganizationLevel.objects.create(
        organization=org,
        parent=None,
        name="Level1"
    )

    unit = OrganizationUnit.objects.create(
        name="Unit Name",
        organization_level=lvl,
    )
```

Note that `YourModel.objects.create()` *does* create the record in the database so you don't need to call `.save()` on your instances here.

Then when you want to add a  child level or child unit you have to pass either the parent instance (not it's id - the instance itself) as `parent` argument OR pass the parent instance id as `parent_id` argument (same for any ForeignKey actually: either your pass 'fieldname=related_instance' or 'fieldname_id=related_instance_id).

Answer (score 1):

what if you change your Organitation level models:

```
class OrganizationLevel(models.Model):
organization = models.ForeignKey(
    Organization,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    db_index=False
)
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    'self',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    db_index=False,
    blank=True, 
    null=True
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'organization_level'
    unique_together = ('name', 'organization')
```